# how to override a maven mojo's "@execute phase"?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, appengine-maven-plugin

I'm using the appengine-maven-plugin, and having a problem with its "update" goal -- it's executing the "package" phase as a prerequisite:

```
/**
 * @goal update
 * @execute phase="package"
 */
public class Update extends AbstractAppCfgMojo {
  @Override
  public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
....
```

However, I need it to do a "clean" first, then do the "package".  Is there a way I can override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried ''mvn clean appengine:update" ? That should do.

EDIT : There is a way to run mvn clean before each build, that might be good enough for you ? Note that it means that your local devserver's datastore will be completely deleted each time you run mvn appengine:devserver. (based on [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/usage.html)):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It will perform a clean before each build.

Comment: Yes, that would work of course, but what I want to ensure is that whenever the appengine:udpate goal is executed, the "clean" phase is executed as a prerequisite.  The problem I'm having is that sometimes the wrong code is getting deployed, because the "compile" phase is performed with one profile activated, but the "appengine:update" goal is performed with another profile activated.  Since the "appengine:update" goal just runs the "package" phase as a prerequisite and the code is already compiled, the wrong code gets packaged and deployed.

Comment: Good idea, but I tried it and it runs the "clean" *after* the "package" goal!

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer with a way to execute the clean before each build. The biggest issue with that is if you need to keep test data in the devserver : it will lose its datastore data each time you run a build.

Comment: Thanks; it's a "big hammer", but this will get the job done, so I'll accept it.  If anyone else knows of a way to just override the "execute phase" of a mojo, please chime in.